# Parse error "/@" in href on mvc razor

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller

I've a syntax error on my razor page when I use the following href

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/2255+Honolulu+Ave+%231a,+Montrose,+CA+91020,+USA/@34.2055466,-118.2289469,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2ea128474a255:0x54f73695881863c3!8m2!3d34.2055466!4d-118.2267582"></a>
```

In the link above there is `USA/@34` part, which isn't recognized by the razor engine.
I've made research and it's suggested to use `@@` to solve the problem.
But in my case the problem is `/@`. When I write

`USA@34` it's ok

`USA/34` also is ok

but `USA/@34` causes syntax error
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `@` is used to print the result of expressions on razor pages. Your solution will be to use `\@@` in the url.

You can also do this:

```
@{
    var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/2255+Honolulu+Ave+%231a,+Montrose,+CA+91020,+USA/@34.2055466,-118.2289469,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2ea128474a255:0x54f73695881863c3!8m2!3d34.2055466!4d-118.2267582";
}

<a href="@url"></a>
```